# Need help on select statement to be used in laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, select

```
select distinct clientID from Client where clientID not in (select clientID from courseDetails inner join course on coursedetails.courseID = course.courseID where coursedetails.courseID = '$courseID')
```

Comment: please check, https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your query is a complex one then you can use `RAW` query in `laravel` like:

```
$data = DB::select(DB::raw('your query'));
```

[Reference](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries)

**Note:** DB::raw() is used to make arbitrary SQL commands which aren't parsed any further by the query builder. They therefore can create a vector for attack via SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a starting point:

```
$results = DB::table('Client')
->whereNotIn('clientID', function($query) use ($courseID) {
    $query->select('clientID')
    ->from('courseDetails')
    ->join('course', 'courseDetails.courseID', '=', 'course.courseID')
    ->where('coursedetails.courseID', '=', $courseID);
})->get();
```

This should get you going. You can tweak it as you want to get your expected result.

Adding to @Mayank answer, you can run raw SQL and pass parameter like this

```
$result = DB::select('select distinct... where coursedetails.courseID = ? ', [$courseID]);
```